# Topic subscriber didn't receive a message

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I recently work with Topic in jms and I have a problem. My TopicSubscriber didn't receive message from publisher and I don't understand why.

Here is my TopicPublisher:

```
public class Publisher
{
    private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BrokerService service = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI("broker:(" + CONNECTION_URL + ")"));
        service.start();
        TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(CONNECTION_URL);

        // create a topic connection
        TopicConnection topicConn = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();

        // create a topic session
        TopicSession topicSession = topicConn.createTopicSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // lookup the topic object
        Topic topic = topicSession.createTopic("test");

        // create a topic publisher
        TopicPublisher topicPublisher = topicSession.createPublisher(topic);
        topicPublisher.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

        // create the "Hello World" message
        TextMessage message = topicSession.createTextMessage();
        message.setText("Hello World");

        // publish the messages
        topicPublisher.publish(message);

        // print what we did
        System.out.println("Message published: " + message.getText());

        // close the topic connection
        topicConn.close();
    }
}
```

My TopicSubscriber:

```
public class Subscriber
{
    private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(CONNECTION_URL);

        // create a topic connection
        TopicConnection topicConn = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();

        // create a topic session
        TopicSession topicSession = topicConn.createTopicSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);


        Topic topic = topicSession.createTopic("test");

        // create a topic subscriber
        TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber = topicSession.createSubscriber(topic);

        // start the connection
        topicConn.start();

        // receive the message
        TextMessage message = (TextMessage) topicSubscriber.receiveNoWait();

        // print the message
        System.out.println("Message received: " + message.getText());

        // close the topic connection
        topicConn.close();
    }
}
```

In my subscriber I've got a NullPointer on `message.getText()`
What is that problem? What am I doing wrong and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure the `NullPointerException` is on `topicSubscriber.receiveNoWait()`? That would indicate `topicSubscriber` is `null`. It seems more likely that the `NullPointerException` is coming from `message.getText()` because `message` is `null`. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, I mean message.getText() is null. But its because subscriber didn't receive a message. And I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're sending the message before you create the subscription. JMS topics use publish-subscribe semantics where any message published goes to all subscriptions. If there are no subscriptions then the message is discarded.

Also, since you're using `receiveNoWait()` you're severely reducing the chance that your client will ever get a message. In order for your client to actually receive a message the message would have to be sent in between the time you call `createSubscriber(topic)` and the time you call `receiveNoWait()`. Since those 2 calls happen very close together the window of time is very small.

If you really want your subscriber to get a message then run `Subscriber` first and use `receive()` rather than `receiveNoWait()` and then run `Publisher`. This will ensure the subscription exists when the message is sent and that the client waits to receive the message before exiting.